# No X-Axis labels for mermaid gantt chart in Azure DevOps Wiki

Tags: azure-devops

I want to document a roadmap as a mermaid Gantt chart in the Azure DevOps Wiki.
I am using following example (taken from mermaid web page):

```
::: mermaid
gantt
    title A Gantt Diagram
    dateFormat  YYYY-MM-DD
        axisFormat  %m/%d/%Y

    section Section
    A task           :a1, 2014-01-01, 30d
    Another task     :after a1, 20d

    section Another
    Task in sec      :2014-01-12, 12d
    another task      : 24d
:::
```

But the X-Axis is not getting any X-Axis legend when being rendered in the browser so it is not visible when a task starts and ends.
Pasting the same code into the mermaid live editor it works fine, see [here](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/#/edit/eyJjb2RlIjoiZ2FudHRcblx0dGl0bGUgQSBHYW50dCBEaWFncmFtXG5cdGRhdGVGb3JtYXQgIFlZWVktTU0tRERcblx0c2VjdGlvbiBTZWN0aW9uXG5cdEEgdGFzayAgICAgICAgICAgOmExLCAyMDE0LTAxLTAxLCAzMGRcblx0QW5vdGhlciB0YXNrICAgICA6YWZ0ZXIgYTEgICwgMjBkXG5cdHNlY3Rpb24gQW5vdGhlclxuXHRUYXNrIGluIHNlYyAgICAgIDoyMDE0LTAxLTEyICAsIDEyZFxuXHRhbm90aGVyIHRhc2sgICAgICA6IDI0ZFxuXHRcdFx0XHRcdCIsIm1lcm1haWQiOnsidGhlbWUiOiJkZWZhdWx0In0sInVwZGF0ZUVkaXRvciI6dHJ1ZX0).

Comment: Could you update with picture on what is no X-Axis label? https://imgur.com/a/K5QdJBY This is what displayed on my azure devops wiki and you can see it has x-axis there.

Comment: I am using the same code of yours and did not do any modify. In addition, the sprint my org locating is M164 (which is the latest one). You can check from F12 to see the sprint # if your wiki is not same with mine. Just click on org and you will see multiple css files loaded. Click them and see right panel.

Comment: I found the reason. When I use the bright theme all is fine. Switching to dark theme the X-Axis goes away/is not visible.

Comment: emmm... You are not the first one who affected by this dark theme:-( Anyway, awesome you find the cause. Could you share this as answer? I think there must many users who have similar troubles with you.

Comment: Can this be filed as an issue for DevOps?

Comment: Yes, of course. We has received multiple such report about dark theme. Meanwhile our team is still working on reduce its affect as much as possible.

Comment: This was closed as low priority in 2019? https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Dark-theme-hides-text-in-Mermaid-Gantt-c/840221

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. When I use the bright theme all is fine. Switching to dark theme the X-Axis goes away/is not visible.